# passing primitive int array class (int[].class) to a generic method which expects Class<T[]> fails to compile

Tags: java, arrays, generics, primitive

I have following code:

```
public class Test {

    private Map<String, Object> delegate;

    public Test(Map<String, Object> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public <T> T[] getValueAsArray(String key, Class<T[]> arrayClz) {
        T[] ret = null;
        Object val = delegate.get(key);
        if (val != null && arrayClz != null && arrayClz.isInstance(val)) {
            ret = (T[]) val;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> delegate = new HashMap<>();
        int[] intArray = new int[3];
        intArray[0] = 1;
        intArray[1] = 2;
        intArray[2] = 3;
        delegate.put("intArray", intArray);

        Integer[] integerArray = new Integer[3];
        integerArray[0] = 1;
        integerArray[1] = 2;
        integerArray[2] = 3;
        delegate.put("integerArray", integerArray);

        Test test = new Test(delegate);
        //int[] a = test.getValueAsArray("intArray", int[].class);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        Integer[] b = test.getValueAsArray("integerArray", Integer[].class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }

}
```

If I uncomment the following code from the above class, it does not compile.

```
    //int[] a = test.getValueAsArray("intArray", int[].class);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error:(44, 31) java: method getValueAsArray in class com.jpmorgan.cu.collections.Test cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<T[]>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<int[]>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: int
    bound(s): java.lang.Object
```

Can someone explain why does this not work? I was under assumption that array is Object, so int[] and Integer[] are different but both are Objects.
What is the best way to make this method work for primitive arrays as well as object arrays?

Comment: It will never work for arrays with  primitive type components. `T[]` declares an array with a generic component type. Primitives do not work with generics.

Comment: The title is wrong. `int[].class` can perfectly be passed to something which expects `Class<T>`. Just not something which expects `Class<T[]>`.

Comment: *I was under assumption that array is Object, so int[] and Integer[] are different but both are Objects.* `Integer` and `String` are also subclasses of `Object`, but that doesn't make them interchangeable with each other or with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[]` is a reference type. `Integer[]` is a reference type. `int` is a primitive type. `Integer` is a reference type.

`T[]` describes an array type where the component type is the generic type `T`, to be bound at some point.

If you call

```
Integer[] b = test.getValueAsArray("integerArray", Integer[].class);
```

you're trying to bind `Integer` to `T`. That will work since `Integer` is a reference type, which can be used with the unbounded generic type variable `T`.

But if you call

```
test.getValueAsArray("integerArray", int[].class);
```

you are trying to bind `int` to `T`. This will not work because generic types only work with reference types and `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: Just to make it complete, can you please suggest better ways to implement this functionality where it can work with both primitive arrays as well as arrays of reference types?

Comment: @wildnux There is not solution with generics. You'll need to provide a method for each primitive type as a return type.